# Meaning of "central registration system" in Japanese clinical trials

Tags: terminology, clinical-study

[Quote](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30013356) from a Japanese clinical trial report:

> METHOD: An observational study was conducted on patients who relapsed after primary systemic therapy with TZM using **the central registration system**. The primary end point was progression-free survival (PFS). Secondary end points consisted of the response rate, overall survival (OS), and safety.

Is there some state-wide centralized system in Japan for registering all clinical trial participants? If not, what is the meaning of "**the** central registration system"?